# random numbers generated in java

Tags: java, random

I am generating a set of random numbers using Random class object but the generated set of random numbers are all differnt i.e, none of them have the same value.
I have run the program many times but everytime the random values generated are different. i.e. none of them is same.

```
 int i,j,ex,counter=0;
    int size=7,count=1;
    boolean track=false;
    List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        track=false;
        Random rn = new Random(i);
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            int k = rn.nextInt(364);
            digits.add(k);
        }


       for (j = 0; j < digits.size(); j++)
        {
          System.out.println(digits.get(j));
        }


        for (int m=0;m<digits.size();m++)
        {
            for (int n=m+1;n<digits.size();n++)
            {
                if (digits.get(m) == digits.get(n))
                {
                    counter++;
                    //System.out.println(counter);
                    track=true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if(track)
                break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(100*(double)(counter/count));

}
```

}

but on every new run some of the random number based on probability could be same, but never (unless size>364) I get same random numbers.

Comment: Ambiguity ---> `everytime the random values generated are same. i.e. none of them is same.`?

Comment: Well, what is `i`?  You have to use the same seed if you want the same values.

Comment: Javas `Ramdom` class is a *pseudo random generator*. The sequence of numbers generated depends on the *seed* passed in via constructor. The default constructor uses `new Date().getTime()`as seed. Since you give the same numbers as seeds in each program run (`new Random(i)`) you always get the same sequence of "random" results. Of cause you could have looked up this in the public API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Random numbers are supposed to be random, that is, not the same. You can get the same set of numbers by giving the random number generator the same seed.

Comment: @OP did you mean to ask why none of the generated numbers are equal to each other in a generated sample ?

Comment: but on every new run some of the random number based on probability could be same, but never (unless size>364) I get same random numbers.

Comment: try printing out your variable `k` and also change it to `rn.nextInt(10);` so there is a smaller set to choose numbers from, you will see there are eventually repeats

Comment: Are you saying that if you generate say 50 integers, you always get 50 distinct integers and never repeats?

Comment: Try using `441287210` as the seed.

Comment: @bradimus I believe that is what he is saying

Comment: @bradimus exactly thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Random() class in jave generates a RANDOM number between going from 0 to 364 in your code. 
Which means, in your code, after 365 times generating a number, only then you will be 100% sure there are 2 integers matching eachother, but it's VERY unlikely it will take 365 times!

I hope you understand the working of a random function now?

this could be a possible output of your function with "digits" size 5:

56
201
78
12
360

Comment: I am solving a problem where I need to find how many of the times the generated set of random numbers contains two or more same random numbers. I am getting output as zero everytime.

Comment: and did it return "6" when you generated 370 numbers for example? If not, could you post the code, because the fault is probably there then.

Comment: well surely it will not take 364 randoms before finding a repeat, that is the worst possible case and highly unlikely.

Comment: It's unlikely indeed, but i guess that's what he means.

Comment: most likely the problem exists in another part of the code as JonasAnon has said